# SQL Split, Join & Merge

Tags: sql, sql-server, merge, split, concatenation

TableDO

```
| DOID     | TranID |
| -------- | ------ |
| 1        | 1 2 3  |
| 2        | 2 4    |
```

TblTransporter

```
| TranID   |Transporter |
| -------- | --------   |
| 1        | ABC Tran   |
| 2        | BBC Tran   |
| 3        | CBC Tran   |
| 4        | DBC Tran   |
```

Result require From TableDO

```
| DOID     | Transporter               |
| -------- | --------                  |
| 1        | ABC Tran,BBC Tran,CBC Tran|
| 2        | BBC Tran,DBC Tran         |
```

I have tried

```
Select o.DoNo,t.Transporter as tpt 
  From DO o
 outer apply String_Split(o.Transporter,' ') s
  left join Transporter as t on t.TID = s.value
```

Which Shows Result

```
| DONO     | Tpt        |
| -------- | --------   |
| 1        | ABC Tran   |
| 1        | BBC Tran   |
| 1        | CBC Tran   |
| 2        | BBC Tran   |
| 2        | DBC Tran   |
```

I do not want to use String_Split Function as it requre Database Compatibility.

Comment: Which type of database are you using? `MySQL` or `SQL Server`?

Comment: I am using SQL Server 2019 Express

Comment: What is your `Database Compatibility` level ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with **[STRING_AGG()](https://database.guide/the-sql-server-equivalent-to-group_concat/)**

```
Select o.DoNo,STRING_AGG(t.Transporter,',') as tpt 
  From DO o
 outer apply String_Split(o.Transporter,' ') s
  left join Transporter as t on t.TID = s.value
 GROUP BY o.DoNo
```

Comment: Glad it can help you,can you mark it as accepeted?

Answer (score 0):

This is an other solution using `GROUP BY` and `STRING_AGG` only :

```
select DOID, STRING_AGG(t.Transporter,',') as tpt
from TableDO d
inner join TblTransporter t on cast(d.TranID as varchar) like concat('%',t.TranID, '%')
group by DOID
```

Result :

```
DOID    tpt
1       ABC Tran,BBC Tran,CBC Tran
2       BBC Tran,DBC Tran
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/_cg-lMLA)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for all those who still think SQL Server 2016 is the latest and greatest version:

```sql
DECLARE @do TABLE (doid int, tranid varchar(100))
DECLARE @tblTransporter TABLE (tranID int, transporter varchar(100))

INSERT INTO @do
SELECT  doid, tranid
FROM    (
    VALUES  (1,'1 2 3')
    ,   (2,'2 4')
) t (DOID,TranID)

INSERT INTO @tbltransporter
SELECT  tranid,Transporter
FROM    (
    VALUES  (1,'ABC Tran')
    ,   (2,'BBC Tran')
    ,   (3,'CBC Tran')
    ,   (4,'DBC Tran')
) t (TranID,Transporter)

SELECT  doid
,   STUFF((SELECT   ISNULL(',' + t.transporter, '')
        FROM    (
            SELECT  cast('<root><i>' + replace(tranid, ' ', '</i><i>') + '</i></root>' AS xml) x
            ) x
        CROSS apply x.nodes('root/i') n(n)
        LEFT JOIN @tblTransporter t
            ON  t.tranID = n.value('.', 'INT')
        ORDER BY n.value('.', 'INT')
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
    ).value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), 1, 1, '')
FROM    @do
```

It looks a bit busy but what it does is create an xml from the list of tranIds, and then split it by using nodes, and then concatenates it back using another FOR XML PATH